# ZeroMQ: Address in use error when re-binding socket

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, zeromq

After binding a ZeroMQ socket to an endpoint and closing the socket, binding another socket to the same endpoint requires several attempts. The previous calls to `zmq_bind` up until the successful one fail with the error "Address in use" (`EADDRINUSE`).

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

#include "zmq.h"

int main() {
    void *ctx = zmq_ctx_new();
    assert( ctx );
    void *skt;

    skt = zmq_socket( ctx, ZMQ_REP );
    assert( skt );
    assert( zmq_bind( skt, "tcp://*:5555" ) == 0 );
    assert( zmq_close( skt ) == 0 );

    skt = zmq_socket( ctx, ZMQ_REP );
    assert( skt );
    int fail = 0;
    while ( zmq_bind( skt, "tcp://*:5555" ) ) { ++fail; }
    std::cout << fail << std::endl;
}
```

I'm using ZeroMQ 4.0.3 on Windows XP SP3, compiler is VS 2008. libzmq.dll has been built with the provided Visual Studio solution.

This prints `1` here when doing a "Debug" build (both of the code above and of libzmq.dll) and `0` using a "Release" build. Strange enough, when running the code above with mixed build configuration (Debug with Release lib), `fail` counts up to 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pieter Hintjens gave me the hint [on the mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.network.zeromq.devel/23345):

The call to `zmq_close` initiates the socket shutdown. This is done in a special "reaper" thread started by ZeroMQ to make the call to `zmq_close` asynchronous and non-blocking. See ["The reaper thread"](http://zeromq.org/whitepapers:architecture#toc6) in a whitepaper about ZeroMQ's architecture.

The code above does not wait for the thread doing the actual work, so the endpoint will not become available immediately.

Answer (score 1):

When a TCP socket is closed, it enters a state called `TIME_WAIT`. This means that while the socket is in that state, it's not really closed, and that in turn means that the address used by the socket is not available until it leave the state.

So if you run your program two times in close succession the socket will be in this `TIME_WAIT` state from the first run when you try the second run, and you get an error like this.

You might want to [read more about TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), and especially about its [operation and states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation).

Comment: Looking at the provided TCP state diagram, `TIME_WAIT` can be entered after `SYN_RCVD` or `ESTABLISHED` has been reached. Please note that re-binding works within the program (after a few microseconds). Running the programm *in close succession* works.