# Can I rebind a ZeroMQ socket to a different port without destroying the socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, zeromq

I have a reply ZSocket in a request-reply pattern.

Later in the process, I want to switch the binding, so the reply socket now responds to requests on a different port. The user enters the port that they want to listen on, if they don't want to listen on the default port 5555.

Can I do this by simply calling ZSocket.Bind() again, or do I have to destroy the socket object first.

If I have to destroy it first, then how can I be sure the ZSocket is ready to be rebound to something else now? I know that closing sockets is handled differently in C because it doesn't have garbage collecting. Since the C# language binding for ZeroMQ can use of garbage collecting, is it as simple as closing the socket and creating a new one on another port? Do I need to bother with setting a low Linger value or anything like that?

I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.
Here is a related question [ZeroMQ: Address in use error when re-binding socket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22656225/4262466)

Here is the code I have

```
private ZContext context = new ZContext();
private ZSocket replier = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.REP);
replier.Bind("tcp://*:5555); //bind to default port
//yada yada...
//user enters new port to listen on 5556
replier.Bind("tcp://*:5556);
```

What is the proper way to do this? Please explain the logic behind the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about C# bindings, but you can rebind zmq socket using plain C api and start receiving messages on new port right away. Linger period is unrelated to your case.

Comment: ok, thanks. I read that you have to set linger low and close the socket before it can be released in C for a safe shutdown. Not sure if that applies to rebinding it to another port. I am going to try a simple rebind to see if it works

Comment: Just calling Bind() again on another port will allow me to start receiving messages on that new port however the old port is not available to be bound by something else.

Comment: That's because a zmq socket can be bound to multiple network sockets, so the second bind call adds an extra tcp connection rather than replacing the existing one.

Comment: @ComradeJoecool, just use ZSocket.Unbind() to abandon unused port before binding to the new one.